# Do we need to pass only int values for the 'INT' type data in MYSQL select query?

Tags: mysql

Actually following values are not there in the 'status' column(i.e 1ooo,1ee)" but result is comming. status column is containing only one record that is with the 1.

```
QRY-1:select * from User_Table where key ='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' and status=1;

QRY-2:select * from User_Table where key ='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' and status="1";

QRY-3:select * from User_Table where key ='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' and status="1ooo";

QRY-4:select * from User_Table where key ='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' and status="1ee";
```

QRY-1:OK

For the above QRY-2,QRY-3,QRY-4 also I'm getting same result?Why?

Comment: what is the type of status field? share structure

Answer (score 2):

This happend because the implict convdrsione performed  by SQL  ..  and in each case the firts char (or set of chars ) is valid number

```
'1' , '1ooooì, '1ee'   became 1 for implict conversion to destination type
```

all the queries became

```
select * from User_Table where key ='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' and status=1
```

Answer (score 0):

This occurs because the implicit conversion that happens when an operator is used with operands of different types. In your case, comparing an int with a string. You can see more [Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/type-conversion.html).